# App stuck during installation

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-provisioning

I have developed an application on iOS 6.  I could sign into it with distributed provisioning profile and certificate.  The application is installing on all devices except iPhone 3G.

When I'm installing the app on iPhone 3G, it gets stuck with an installation message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi john it happens because of cpu architecture.i'm sure you have not mentioned the cpu architecture of iPhone 3g.

Go to your build setting >>in valid architecture add Armv6 with existing architecture.

Clean and build,make a new ipa.

Enjoy!!!!!